# How do I get Node.js and express to send back something to a specific HTML element, like a textarea, as is useful in an SPA?

Tags: node.js, single-page-application

I don't want to have to use React or Angular, just send back some data to put somewhere.  I tried res.render() but whatever I put inside the parentheses failed.

Comment: Please add more details such as how did you configured the app and whats the error you are facing?

Comment: function postnote() {
    $.post("/postnote", 
                {
                       message : $("#message").val()
                },
                function (data) {
                           console.log("We got: " + data)
                           $("#response").text(data)
                }
     )
}

Comment: app.post("/postnote", function(req, response) {
   const towrite = (new Date).toString() + "\n-----------------\n" + req.body.message + "\n\n";
   let finalwrite  = fs.readFileSync("public/notes.txt") + towrite
   fs.writeFileSync("public/notes.txt", finalwrite)
   //console.log("in /postnote, writing "+finalwrite)
   // response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
   response.send("Hi there")
});

Comment: Tell whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  It is just that the response wipes out the client's web page entirely and replaces it with "Hi there".  But I want that string to go into a text field, as in a single-page application.

Comment: So you want to send a string as response and it should be added to the existing webpage right?

Comment: Yes, but I want to put it into a textarea because I have an SPA on the client and I want to use Node to fetch/save data on the server.  I can do this so easily in PHP!

Comment: Then you use can ajax at front end to handle this scenario right? How do you handle this in PHP?

Comment: I use jquery's $.post() method in the client, and a simple PHP script that reads the params from $_POST and then emits a return string (via print() or echo) and it comes back to the $.post() call and gets put into the right area.

Comment: Still you are using jquery post and its not working with nodejs. Is that your issue?
If yes, please show the front end code

Comment: I found the problem...  my stupidity!  I can send you the code via email if you want to see the working version, in case you're interested.  I'm going to delete this message soon because it is worthless now.

Answer (score 0):

To use **res.render** you have to define the **view engine**.
Refer - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-render-function/

And if you want to send an HTML file use **res.sendFile**

Comment: I just want to send a string back!  How do I do that?  What I see in the user page is a complete rewrite of the page, the old one disappears and just the simple string shows up.

Comment: Add your code as a code snippet, so that we can look into it.

Comment: ``` lang-js
function postnote() {
    $.post("/postnote", 
                {
                       message : $("#message").val()
                },
                function (data) {
                           console.log("We got: " + data)
                           $("#response").text(data)
                }
     )
}```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to paste in a block of code with mini-formatting to get it to stay like < pre >.